# Dragon Curve in Python Order 10

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, l-systems

Why does my Dragon curve not look like a dragon curve?

[image: Dragon Curve]

Here is the implementation in python with order 10:

```
def setupForDragonCurve():
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.tracer(1e3, 0)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(0, -turtle.window_height()/5)
    turtle.pendown()

def generateDragonCurve(n, result='[FX]'):
    for _ in range(n):
        result = result.replace('Y', 'FX-Y')
        result = result.replace('X', 'X+YF')
    return result

def drawDragonCurve(cmds, size):
    stack = []
    for cmd in cmds:
        if cmd=='F':
            turtle.forward(size)
        elif cmd=='-':
            turtle.left(90)
        elif cmd=='+':
            turtle.right(90)
        elif cmd=='X':
            pass
        elif cmd=='Y':
            pass
        elif cmd=='[':
            stack.append((turtle.position(), turtle.heading()))
        elif cmd==']':
            position, heading = stack.pop()
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.setposition(position)
            turtle.setheading(heading)
            turtle.pendown()
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unknown Cmd: {}'.format(ord(cmd)))
    turtle.update()
```

Here is what it's supposed to look like at order 10:

[image: Dragon Curve]

EDIT: Here is what I get with order 1, with a larger scaled curve:

[image: Dragon Curve Order 1]

Comment: Have you tried a lower-order curve? It might be easier to see the problem that way.

Comment: I meant, like, order 1. Reduce it to the simplest case where you see a problem.

Comment: it seems that I may have implemented the drawing function wrong? I'm not sure, I can draw a fractal plant perfectly as well as a pentigree snowflake... but i just can't get this one :(

Comment: I think i got it... I f'd up, I think Wiki was wrong with one of the rules.... Instead of 'X' -> 'X+YF+' i did 'X' -> 'X+YF'

Comment: Nvm... it's still wrong... You think it's possibly something wrong with my rules? I'm stuck :/ There really isn't anything to check other than the rules right?

Answer (score 1):

When you run

```
    result = result.replace('Y', 'FX-Y')
    result = result.replace('X', 'X+YF')
```

the second line replaces the `X`s introduced by the first line. (Also, you're using the wrong replacement rules, but you seem to have noticed that already.)

You need to carry out these replacements in such a way that they don't interact with each other, probably by doing them in a combined step. One way to do this would be to use the more advanced substitution capabilities of the `re` module. Another would be to write your own replacement routine. You could also use a character other than `X` in the first replacement, so the second replacement doesn't pick it up, then replace that character with `X` in a third pass.